# Reading lines in C and converting to floating point

Tags: c

I have a text file that reads as such:

```
A 50
B 30
C 40
```

Currently my code opens this file and reads each line as thus:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int file = 0;

    {
        char* filename = "commands.txt";
        FILE* file;
        file = fopen(filename, "a+");
        char line[BUFSIZ];
        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
            char first_letter = line[0];
            printf("%c", first_letter);
            float number = line[2 : end] 
            printf("%f", number)

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The character variable `first_letter` is set to the letter. I have written 2:end but obviously that won't work. I would like to set the floating point variable 'number' to whatever the number is on that line. It may not necessarily be a 2 digit number.

Comment: You may need to tokenize the array on `' '` and then apply the `atof` method

Comment: [Your code does not compile](https://ideone.com/Xd2bbG)

Comment: You should probably use `sscanf` on the line you read.

Comment: @LeFlou I think the OP says that themself in the last paragraph...

Comment: what is `int file = 0;`??

Comment: `float number;
            sscanf(line + 2, "%f", &number);`

Comment: `50`, `40`, `30`...look perfect for an `int`...you got any specific reason for making them `float`?

Comment: To add to BLUEPIXY's comment, also always check return value of any *scanf* function (read the docs/man page for what the return value means).

Comment: @SouravGhosh The numbers may not be integers, the example I have given has them as such. They also may be also quite long.

Comment: Thanks @BLUEPIXY, that works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you read, parse it using [`sscanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html):

```
  while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        char first_letter;
        float number;
        if( sscanf(line, "%c %f", &first_letter, &number) != 2)
        { /* handle error */ }
        printf("%c %f\n", first_letter, number);

    }
```